# For which future movies did Stan Lee finish his cameo?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, casting, cameo, stan-lee

Now we all know the great Stan Lee is no more. I am wondering if he has already finished cameos for future Marvel or other movies.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to [inverse.com](https://www.inverse.com/article/50756-stan-lee-cameo-avengers-4), he might appear in 6 unreleased films:

> - **Ralph Breaks the Internet:** It’s unclear whether or not Lee actually lends his voice to Ralph Breaks the Internet, but outlets are
>     labeling it as a cameo, so Lee probably has at least one line.
> - **Madness in the Method:** Lee’s credited as “Stan,” which probably means he plays himself, a continuation of his iconic role in Mallrats
>     (1995). Madness in the Method has no confirmed release date, having
>     been seemingly stuck in post-production for quite some time now, but
>     it’s expected by the end of 2018, according to IMDb
> - **Captain Marvel:** There’s no real confirmation just yet about whether or not Stan Lee filmed a cameo for Captain Marvel, but
>     considering he definitely has one in Avengers 4 and Captain Marvel
>     comes out before that, it seems likely. Production on the two movies
>     overlapped somewhat, so it stands to reason Lee might’ve filmed a
>     cameo alongside Carol Danvers around the same time he did for Avengers
>     4.
> - **Avengers 4:** Stan Lee will definitely appear in Avengers 4 in some fashion. Director Joe Russo has confirmed that Lee filmed his
>     cameo for Ant-Man and the Wasp at the same time he did for Avengers 4.
> - **Spider-Man: Far From Home:** Much like with Captain Marvel, Stan Lee is expected to have some kind of cameo in Spider-Man: Far From
>     Home. Especially because he typically filmed his cameos in batches,
>     it’s possible that he filmed the Far From Home cameo around the same
>     time he filmed one for Venom — both films were produced by Sony
>     Pictures.

They added ***Dark Phoenix*** in the list too but [EW](https://ew.com/movies/2018/11/12/stan-lee-no-cameo-x-men-dark-phoenix/) confirms Stan Lee does not have a cameo in the next X-Men film ***Dark Phoenix***.

And [express.co.uk](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/1044729/Stan-Lee-future-cameos-Marvel-boss-Kevin-Feige-Avengers-4-Spider-Man-Captain-Marvel-X-Men) confirm his cameo for ***Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse***, ***Captain Marvel*** and ***Avengers 4***.